# Can I safely run shielded Cat6A cable indoors without conduit?

Tags: ethernet, wiring, power-over-ethernet

I bought [this cable](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09CR62FWW) to run PoE Cat 6A cables to a few cameras and access points around my house.

I was not planning on running them through conduit, but I am not doubting if that is a safe choice given a few things I've read online.

Is there anything to know about the code or pros / cons of doing this without a conduit?

Comment: That sounds more like a DIY.SE question than a SuperUser question.

Answer (score 2):

You can safely run CAT 6 and CAT 5 shielded cable indoors not in conduit.

This is done frequently in numerous buildings. No issue.

Make sure the cable in not kinked in installation and stays an inch or two (5 cm) from power lines. Make sure it is not near sharp edges (furnace pipes for example) which can cut the cable.

Install properly indoors, no issue to not use a conduit.

I run POE cable here for my Ubiquiti AP not in conduit and it works very well.

Answer (score 2):

This is safe and a common practice.  POE is extra-low voltage (less then 50v), so there is little risk of shock or fire. The risks are more around cable non-performance/signal loss.

In many (I expect most) countries you can legally do this work yourself (In New Zealand we can, Aussies are not supposed to - that seems to be a union/labour protection thing to me)

There are lots of "gotchas" if you are worried about getting the cabling to spec - and if you need to ask you likely won't get it to spec. The cables will still work but may have a bit more signal loss.  If you want perfect, you need to do a lot if reading/studying or engage someone qualified - but in practice it will normally be just fine if you terminate both ends properly.

Some easyish best practices -

- Solid core in walls, multistrand for patch leads.
- Total length including leads less then 100m (I think less then 80m in walls)
- Separate data and power by at least 2inches/50mm. Cross power lines at 90 degrees.
- Dont bend cable to sharply (at least 8 times diameter of cable bend radius)
  *Pay attention to cable termination - this is where most problems occur. Google TIA-568